# Not able to access Manage Link in Communities (community workspace)

Tags: community-builder, partner-communities, partner-portal

I have checked the below link, all necessary permissions required for managing communities, everything is properly set (and I am an admin). However, whenever workspace is clicked it always takes me to our custom login page.

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000212095&language=en_US&type=1

Not sure what is wrong with it as its working as expected in other sandboxes. Can anyone please direct me if I missed anything?

Answer (score 1):

On Sys Admin profile under Session settings, following option was checked. When I disabled it, it worked.
"Separate Community and login authentication for internal users"